# In C# I want to wait until I close the browser(In case of default browser). For Specific browser like Chrome or MsEdge I am able to wait

Tags: c#, process.start

I have Implemented the following code,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

process.Dispose();
startInfo = null;
process = null;
return status;
```

I am expecting that process.Start() will open the default browser(it is opening the default browser) but it further continues the flow....
I am expecting that It should wait until I close the default browser.
For Specific browser like Chrome or MsEdge I am able to wait until I close the browser, please have a look for the following code.

```
startInfo.FileName = chrome.exe;
startInfo.Arguments = args + $" --user-data-dir=\"{chromeTempUserDataDir}\"";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

process.Dispose();
startInfo = null;
process = null;
return status;
```

How can I wait until I close the default browser?

Comment: what is the default browser exactly? IE?

Comment: Nope It is "chrome" on my system.